# How to do a DNS lookup without any crates?

Tags: rust, dns

Without using any crates, how can I do a simple DNS lookup using the system's DNS resolver?

Comment: In this case, you may not need a crate but "without any crates" is _**usually**_ a very limiting restriction in Rust, since the language philosophy is to rely on external crates as much as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html#examples,

```
use std::net::{SocketAddr, ToSocketAddrs};

// assuming 'localhost' resolves to 127.0.0.1
let mut addrs_iter = "localhost:443".to_socket_addrs().unwrap();
assert_eq!(addrs_iter.next(), Some(SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 443))));
```

Comment: That will just resolve an IP address. But DNS is so much more powerful - there are TXT,MX,PTR, CNAME,etc, all kinds of different record types which you cannot access with this approach

Comment: That answer returns a `SocketAddr` that contains not just the IP address but also a port. I can append a random port to the hostname string and then just take the `.ip()` to get the `IpAddr`.
But is there an easier way to get an `IpAddr` from the hostname directly?